# not able to tap on MKPinAnnotationView Second Time

Tags: ios, annotations, mapkit, mkannotationview

I have created Custom annotation by using this code.

```
    - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
    {
        static NSString *const AnnotatioViewReuseID = @"AnnotatioViewReuseID";
       // MKAnnotationView

        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotatioViewReuseID];

        if (!annotationView) {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotatioViewReuseID];
        }

        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[FBAnnotationCluster class]]) {
            FBAnnotationCluster *cluster = (FBAnnotationCluster *)annotation;
            cluster.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)cluster.annotations.count];

            UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]init];
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:33.0/255.0 green:191.0/255.0 blue:133.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

            UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
            label.text = cluster.title;
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Medium" size:14.0];
            label.font = font;

            label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [self widthOfString:label.text]+20, [self widthOfString:label.text]+20);

            view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.width) ;

            view.layer.cornerRadius =  view.frame.size.height/2;
            view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
            view.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;

            view.clipsToBounds = true;

            [view addSubview:label];

            for (UIView *view in [annotationView subviews])
            {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
            [annotationView addSubview:view];

            annotationView.enabled = YES;
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

            annotationView.pinTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        } else {

            annotationView.pinTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            annotationView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
            annotationView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;

            FBAnnotation *a = (FBAnnotation*)annotation;

            NSLog(@"amount is %f",a.amount);

            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-marker-select"];

            UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

            NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
            formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
            formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;

            NSString *result = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:a.amount]];

            NSString *strData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",a.currency,result];
            UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Medium" size:14.0];

            NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
            paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                                         NSFontAttributeName : font,
                                         NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle,
                                         NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]
                                         };
            CGSize textSize = [strData sizeWithAttributes:attributes];

            CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(5, (image.size.height-textSize.height)/2 - 2, textSize.width , textSize.height);

            UILabel *textLable = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:textRect];

            textLable.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            textLable.font = font;
            textLable.text = strData;

            UIImage *lightSymImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_lightning"];

           UIImageView *lightImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

            lightImage.image = lightSymImg;

            CGRect imgRect = CGRectMake(textRect.origin.x+textRect.size.width, (image.size.height-lightSymImg.size.height)/2 - 2, lightSymImg.size.width,lightSymImg.size.height);

            lightImage.frame = imgRect;

            imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, imgRect.size.width + imgRect.origin.x+5, image.size.height);

            imgView.image = image;

            for (UIView *view in [annotationView subviews])
            {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;

            [annotationView addSubview:imgView];
            [annotationView addSubview:textLable];
            [annotationView addSubview:lightImage];

            annotationView.enabled = YES;
            annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
        }
        return annotationView;
        }
```

And in didSelect method i have written this code for Present a view Controller

```
 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
    {
        NSLog(@"didSelectAnnotationView");

        if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[FBAnnotationCluster class]]) {

            NSLog(@"FBAnnotationCluster select annotation");
        }
        else{


            SpotDetailVC *locDetailVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SpotDetail" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SpotDetailVC"];

            [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
```

Now When i click on annotation for the first Time it works but after dismiss that view again click on Same annotation it does not works.

Please help, i know it's Silly mistake but i am not able to configure out that one.

Comment: what happen when you click on first time? it print NSLog(@"FBAnnotationCluster select annotation"); or not ?

Comment: when i click on first Time it goes into didSelectAnnotationView method. but when i click Second time it doesnot call  didSelectAnnotationView methods

Comment: `nil` is assigned to map view's delegate property, when you click on annotation for the first Time?

Comment: how it can be assigned to nil when i click on annotation.

Comment: Another common cause is if the annotation's title is blank.

Comment: okay if it is blank then how it's called for the first time and after presenting one view(dismiss that view) the same annotation does not called. but yes the other annotation called